# Continuous page load content PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I am trying to load content from my database 10 items at a time as the user scrolls through my web page. Right now I can load 10 items on scroll, but how can I load the next 10 items when they scroll more. Currently my php will grab the first 10 items each time, and my scroll function is only running once. I was looking at jscroll but was not really sure about its implimentation.

Here is my code, help appreciated.

PHP:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test");

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  for ($index=0; $index < 10; $index++)
{

    echo '<table border="0" width="600px">';
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><p>" . '<img src="' . $row['image'] . '" hspace="10" border="1" style="float:left;">' . "</p>";
    echo "<p>" . "#" . $row['ID'] . ": " . $row['confession'] . "</p></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flg='1';
    $(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(document).scrollTop());
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >299){
        if(flg=='1')
            {
        $.post('test2.php', function(data) {
                    $('#content').html(data);
        });
         flg='0';
            }
    }
  });});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement "pagination". This is basically an offset and a limit to fetch X rows starting at the offset. If you google for "php pagination tutorial" you'll find plenty of tutorials, [here is one of them](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination).

I think describing the whole concept here in detail with code examples would become a very long answer and there are plenty of tutorials, so just check them out.

Comment: No the answer but it's a good place to start. That tutorial got me running the pagination on my site. However I have one problem. When I click the link to page two it loads a blank page and echos all the data onto that blank page. How can I simply update the div the current data is being echoed into? or is there a better way?

Comment: You have to make an AJAX call when the link is clicked and replace your page content with the response from the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a parameter to the server script telling it where to start from. You can then use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to select the appropriate records in the database to add.